# Resizable autocomplete

Tags: jquery-ui

I've been trying to create a resizable autocomplete (and I'm not even sure if this would be possible!). I've tried a lot of things getting ideas from google but have not been able to accomplish it. 
The code I've creates a resizable menu but it's not aligned to the bottom of the text box and when I search the 2nd time the resize option disappears. Is there a way of fixing it or can this functionality be achieved in any other way?

```
    <head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="~/css/1.8/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="~/script/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/script/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <style>
        .ui-resizable-se
        {
            bottom: 0px;
        }
        .ui-autocomplete
        {
            background: silver;
            overflow-y: hidden; /* prevent horizontal scrollbar */
            overflow-x: hidden;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            var availableTags = [
            "ActionScript",
            "AppleScript",
            "Asp",
            "BASIC",
            "C",
            "C++",
            "Clojure",
            "COBOL",
            "ColdFusion",
            "Erlang",
            "Fortran",
            "Groovy",
            "Haskell",
            "Java",
            "JavaScript",
            "Lisp",
            "Perl",
            "PHP",
            "Python",
            "Ruby",
            "Scala",
            "Scheme"
        ];
            $("#tags").autocomplete({
                source: availableTags,
                open: function (event, ui) {
                    $('ul.ui-autocomplete').resizable();
                }
            });
        });

        $(function () {
            $("#ul.ui-autocomplete").resizable({
                handles: "se"
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div class="ui-widget">
        <label for="tags">
            Tags:
        </label>
        <input id="tags">

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: I need something like the resizable control functionality (http://jqueryui.com/resizable/). I should be able to resize the autocomplete menu (the results that are displayed) vertically and horizontally like the resizable control.

Answer (score 0):

It does work for me with different versions of jquery and jquery ui (resizing autocomplete dropdown).

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gU5Tb/)

Comment: @Oskars Pakers Fiddle works only fix time. If autocomplete is opened at second time, it cannot resized. How to fix ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fiddle that works:

http://jsfiddle.net/gU5Tb/3/

Your version of jQuery and jQuery UI are deprecated.

```
<html>
   <head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="~/css/1.8/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="~/script/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/script/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <style>
        .ui-resizable-se
        {
            bottom: 0px;
        }
        .ui-autocomplete
        {
            background: silver;
            overflow-y: hidden; /* prevent horizontal scrollbar */
            overflow-x: hidden;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            var availableTags = [
            "ActionScript",
            "AppleScript",
            "Asp",
            "BASIC",
            "C",
            "C++",
            "Clojure",
            "COBOL",
            "ColdFusion",
            "Erlang",
            "Fortran",
            "Groovy",
            "Haskell",
            "Java",
            "JavaScript",
            "Lisp",
            "Perl",
            "PHP",
            "Python",
            "Ruby",
            "Scala",
            "Scheme"
        ];
            $("#tags").autocomplete({
                source: availableTags,
                open: function (event, ui) {
                    $('ul.ui-autocomplete').resizable();
                }
            });
        });

        $(function () {
            $("#ul.ui-autocomplete").resizable({
                handles: "se"
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div class="ui-widget">
        <label for="tags">
            Tags:
        </label>
        <input id="tags">

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just tested on Chrome, does not work after losing focus (no resizing available).